# how to make rss feeds unclickable in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss

i have  created wordpress blog and i added the rss widget that comes with wordpress.

but i need to make the rss feeds unclickable to so that my blog visitors will stay in my site and not leave, so i want clicking on an item in the feeds to do nothing.

i have tried to look in rss.php file but i didn't know what to do...
i want the href to be removed.

or if anyone can suggest a rss widget plogin that doesn't link to its source!

can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable clicks using jQuery. Try adding this to your functions.php.

```
add_action('wp_footer','unclickable_rss');

function unclickable_rss() {
  ?>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.widget_rss a').on('click',function() {
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  <?php 
}
```